# Appending to a list in an instantiated object

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to append items to a list in an instantiated object:

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self, name, contents=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.contents = contents


living_room = Room('living room')
dining_room = Room('dining room')

print(living_room.contents)  # []
print(dining_room.contents)  # []

living_room.contents.append('lamp')

print(living_room.contents)  # ['lamp']
print(dining_room.contents)  # ['lamp']
```

The behavior I would expect would be for the lamp to be in living_room.contents, but not in dining_room.contents. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contents` is a mutable default argument. It's default value (the empty list) is only created once, not for every call.

Here are more details:
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

Comment: That's true, but I'm not sure that it addresses the question entirely. I didn't call the instantiated object again, I appended something to it and it also appended to another instantiated object of the same class. Is it really true that you can't add things to a list in an instantiated object?

Comment: As far as I know, the default argument is created in the scope of the function which in turn is created in the scope of the class. So all instances  of `Room` share the list. You can hand each instance its own list if you want them to be independent: `Room('living room', contents=[])`

Comment: OK, thank you. What I wound up doing was just putting self.contents = [] in the body of the __init__ method and leaving contents out of the arguments.

Comment: If you plan on instantiating Room and occasionally passing contents then you could easily do the following! Use a check to determine the value of contents (if contents == []:
            self.__contents = []
        else:
            self.__contents = contents) This allows you the flexibility you originally desired, however I would recommend removing the default parameter!